# Search a list inside a list in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Meeting classes which each class include another class of strings, I want to search each Meeting class if its list of strings contains specific key. If it does, then return this meeting

I wrote the code below, but it returns a list of strings. PS: _meetings is a list

```
        List<Meeting> meetings = _meetings.SelectMany(m => m.AuthinticatedUsers_Id.Where(s => s == App.user.Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: AuthinticatedUsers_Id is the list of strings inside the Meeting class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not projecting, as your input is a list of meetings, and so is your output. Use `Where` to filter the meetings instead of using `Select` or `SelectMany`. The check for a user in the sublist can be done using the `Any` method

```
List<Meeting> meetings = _meetings.Where(m => m.AuthinticatedUsers_Id.Any(s => s == App.user.Id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Meeting> meetings = _meetings.Where(m => m.AuthinticatedUsers_Id.Contains(App.user.Id)).ToList();
```